# Binary Sequence Block

Tags: sequences-and-series, binary

More of an informatics question, rather than applied mathematics -

[image: Problem Statement]
[image: Problem Statement]

Source - Zonal Informatics Olympiad 2011 Question Paper

Although, I've tried a few brute methods, I haven't really understood the actual logic with which it was meant to be solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems familiar. Check [Burrows–Wheeler transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burrows%E2%80%93Wheeler_transform).

Comment: That's it! Thanks a lot mate...

Answer (score 1):

I just found a solution for the (a) sequence :

0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 (first row)

The complete ordered matrix is as follows :

0   0   1   1   0   1   1   1

0   1   1   0   1   1   1   0

0   1   1   1   0   0   1   1

1   0   0   1   1   0   1   1

1   0   1   1   1   0   0   1

1   1   0   0   1   1   0   1

1   1   0   1   1   1   0   0

1   1   1   0   0   1   1   0

During the solutions development i found some useful theorems that help accomplish the solution.

I'll post this as soon as possible.--> No more necessary, the inversion algorithm provided in the wikipedia page provide the necessary solution.

Cheers,

Yassine